# In every new project after npm install this error occur when i run the project

Tags: html, css, angular

In every new project after npm install this error occur when i run the project

Error: multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.scss ../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\subha jha\subha useful\slfr\node_modules\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.css' in 'E:\subha jha\subha useful\slfr\lokfr-repo'

Comment: Do the spaces in the urls have to be %20

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: serve project again!

Comment: hi @kian I serve it again but no changes...

Comment: @Community I tried to  serve the project and it shows some error like this

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth but I don't think so it is a urls problem.